# "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype" при существующем методе в родительском классе

Tags: java

Есть класс, который наследуется от org.junit.Assert:

```
import org.junit.Assert;

public class CustomAssert extends Assert {
    @Override
    static public void assertTrue(String message, boolean condition) {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

Хочу переопределить метод родительского класса

```
static public void assertTrue(String message, boolean condition)
```

Но когда ставлю над ним аннотацию @Override, получаю ошибку:
Error:(7, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема, ведь в родительском классе есть метод с таким же именем и с точно такой же сигнатурой (я его скопировал из родительского)?

Кусок кода из родительского класса:

```
public class Assert {

    protected Assert() {
    }


    static public void assertTrue(String message, boolean condition) {
        if (!condition) {
            fail(message);
        }
    }
.......
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что в суперклассе переопределяемый метод - static. Static методы нельзя переопределять. Их можно "перекрыть" (не указывать аннотацию `@Override`), но тогда полиморфное использование методов при наследовании будет недоступно. И это будет не переопределение, это будет - перекрытие.

Приведу пример для ясности

1. Перекрытие

   ```
   public class Main {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           A a = new A();
           A b = new B();

           a.doSomething(a);
           b.doSomething(b);
       }

   }

   class A {
       public static A doSomething(A a) {
           System.out.println("A");
           return a;
       }
   }

   class B extends A {
       public static A doSomething(A a) {
           System.out.println("B");
           return a;
       }
   }


   * Output: A A
   ```
2. Переопределение

   ```
   public class Main {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           A a = new A();
           A b = new B();

           a.doSomething(a);
           b.doSomething(b);
       }

   }

   class A {
       public A doSomething(A a) {
           System.out.println("A");
           return a;
       }
   }

   class B extends A {
       @Override
       public  A doSomething(A a) {
           System.out.println("B");
           return a;
       }
   }
   * Output: A B
   ```

Comment: Вы бы хоть написали, что если в первом примере создать экземпляр `B` типа `B`, а не `A`, то вызовется метод класса `B`, и в консоль выведется `B`!